# Cant make Associations sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Im trying to create association between two tables using models that are generated by sequelize-cli. But it is not making the relations in db.

Model User

```
    User.hasMany(models.Albums, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'userAlbums'
    });
  };
```

Model Album

```
Albums.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Albums.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      onDelete: 'cascade'
    });
  };
```

Comment: could you please send us the whole model definition  ?